# Do Unity functions that are obsolete still work.

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I am converting a project from Unity 4.x to 5.x and there are a number of functions that the Unity compiler is warning me that are no longer supported or are obsolete.

My question is do these functions still work?  (even though they are marked as obsolete)

I know at some point they need to be updated to the newer API but for the moment I just need to fix the bugs so that the game works.  Are these functions still usable? or are they potentially the source of runtime bugs?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

All obsolete functions has been replaced with new functions. So should take a backup and update your project. Go to Assets->Run API Updater, if your project in not getting updated automatically. Dont worry unity will take care of most of the things.

Comment: So for now if I see `WARNING: 'UnityEngine.GameObject.active' is obsolete. GameObject.active is obsolete. Use GameObject.SetActive(), GameObject.activeSelf or GameObject.activeInHierarchy.` for example it is safe to leave it?

Comment: 'GameObject.active' has been replaced with 'GameObject.activeSelf '. if you want you can leave it, but it's better you should update for future compatibility.

Comment: OK thanks - good to know.  I definitely need to update it but I have to make a load of updates to physics stuff first.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's still work ! They just only warning it.
But i suggest you should change for better result, Unity 5 will update you code from old project, then you should change it following warning, just replace

```
using "xxxx" instead.
```

to the current context.

Comment: Thanks - Could you explain though what you mean by "You should change it following warning etc...

Comment: It will log to you console with warning like example
"The camera.main.active is obsolete. using SetActive() instead"
Then you should change camera.main.active = true to camera.main.SetActive(true)

Comment: Sorry for my bad English that it can't be explain to clarify my understanding to you Y_Y